# Two select box and one check box validation for Monday In Time (selectbox) and Out Time using jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, plugins

*I am very new to JQuery Validation plugin.*

I have used the JQuery Validation plugin and unable to use validation like I did in my JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod("mondayincheck", function(value,element) {
            if($('#hoomonon').val() == '' && $('#hoomonout').val() != '') {
                return true;
           } else {
                return false;
           }
        },"<br>* Choose Monday Out Time"
    );

    /*$.validator.addMethod("mondayoutcheck", function(value, element) {
           return ($('#hoomonon').val() == '' && $('#hoomonout').val() != '')
        }, "<br>* Choose Monday Out Time"
    );*/

    /*$("#signupform").validate({
        rules: {
            telephone: {
                required: function(element) {
                    if ($("#mobile").val().length > 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            },
            mobile: {
                required: function(element) {
                    if ($("#telephone").val().length > 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });*/

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#postadd").validate({
        rules: {
            hoomonon: {
                required : function(element) {
                    //alert($('#hoomonon').val() == '' && $('#hoomonout').val() == '' && $('#hoomonoff:checked') == false);
                    if(($('#hoomonon').val() == '' && $('#hoomonout').val() == '') || ($('#hoomonoff:checked') == false)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                },
                mondayincheck : true
            },
            /*hoomonout: {
                required : function(element) {
                    if($('#hoomonon').val() != '' && $('#hoomonout').val() == '') {
                        return true;
                    } 
                }
            },*/
            hootueon: {
                required:true
            },
            hootueout: {
                required:true
            },
            hoowedon: {
                required:true
            },
            hoowedout: {
                required:true
            },
            hoothuon: {
                required:true
            },
            hoothuout: {
                required:true
            },
            hoofrion: {
                required:true
            },
            hoofriout: {
                required:true
            },
            hoosaton: {
                required:true
            },
            hoosatout: {
                required:true
            },
            hoosunon: {
                required:true
            },
            hoosunout: {
                required:true
            }           
        },      
        messages: {
            hoomonon: {
                required : "<br>* Choose Monday Timing or Closed"
            },
            /*hoomonout: {
                required : "<br>* Choose Monday Out Time"
            },*/
            hootueon: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hootueout: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoowedon: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoowedout: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoothuon: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoothuout: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoofrion: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoofriout: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoosaton: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoosatout: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoosunon: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            },
            hoosunout: {
                required : "<br>* Required Field"
            }           
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

The below is the form which i am validating using JQuery Validation plugin, but I don't know how to validate the below form. I have tried lot of options but they have been unsuccessful

```
<form id="postadd" name="postadd" method="post" action="" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="9%" height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Mon : </td>
                <td width="30%" align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoomonon" id="hoomonon">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>
                </select> 
                  - </td>
                <td width="29%" align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoomonout" id="hoomonout">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>
                </select></td>
                <td width="32%" height="40" align="left" valign="middle" class="txt"><label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="hoomonoff" id="hoomonoff" value="Closed" />
                </label>
                  Closed</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Tue : </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hootueon" id="hootueon">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                    <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select> 
                  - </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hootueout" id="hootueout">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
<option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td height="40" align="left" valign="middle" class="txt"><input type="checkbox" name="hootueoff" id="hootueoff" value="Closed" /> 
                  Closed </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Wed : </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoowedon" id="hoowedon">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoowedout" id="hoowedout">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td height="40" align="left" valign="middle" class="txt"><input type="checkbox" name="hoowedoff" id="hoowedoff" value="Closed" />
                  Closed </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Thu : </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoothuon" id="hoothuon">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoothuout" id="hoothuout">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td height="40" align="left" valign="middle" class="txt"><input type="checkbox" name="hoothuoff" id="hoothuoff" value="Closed" />
                  Closed</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Fri : </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoofrion" id="hoofrion">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoofriout" id="hoofriout">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td height="40" align="left" valign="middle" class="txt"><input type="checkbox" name="hoofrioff" id="hoofrioff" value="Closed" /> 
                  Closed </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Sat : </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoosaton" id="hoosaton">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoosatout" id="hoosatout">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td height="40" align="left" valign="middle" class="txt"><input type="checkbox" name="hoosatoff" id="hoosatoff" value="Closed" />
                  Closed </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30" align="left" valign="middle">Sun : </td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoosunon" id="hoosunon">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td align="left" valign="middle"><select class="timinput" name="hoosunout" id="hoosunout">
                <option value=''>--------Time--------</option>
                  <option value='1:00 AM'>1:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='1:30 AM'>1:30 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:00 AM'>2:00 AM</option>
                  <option value='2:30 AM'>2:30 AM</option>                </select></td>
                <td height="40" align="left" valign="middle" class="txt"><input type="checkbox" name="hoosunoff" id="hoosunoff" value="Closed" />
                Closed</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </form>


I am using Jquery Validation plugin in this php page for above form, 


I want to validate like this javascript using jquery validation plugin


if(hoomononval == '' && hoomonoutval == '' && document.postadd.hoomonoff.checked==false) {
        alert('Please Choose Monday Timing or Closed');
        hoomonon.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(hoomononval != '') {
        if(hoomonoutval == '') {
            alert('Please Choose Monday Out Time');
        hoomonout.focus();
        return false;
        } else if(hoomononval == hoomonoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Monday In & Out Time');
            hoomonon.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoomonoutval != '') {
        if(hoomononval == '') {
            alert('Please Choose Monday In Time');
            hoomonon.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(hoomononval == hoomonoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Monday In & Out Time');
            hoomonon.focus();
            return false;
        } 
    }

    if(hoomononval !='' && hoomonoutval !='') {
            var g   =   0;
            if (document.postadd.hoomonoff.checked==true)
            { 
                //alert('good');
                g++;
            }

        if(g == 1) {
            alert("Don't Choose timing if you choose Closed & Viceversa");
            hoomonoff.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hootueonval == '' && hootueoutval == '' && document.postadd.hootueoff.checked==false) {
        alert('Please Choose Tuesday Timing or Closed');
        hootueon.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(hootueonval != '') {
        if(hootueoutval == '') {
        alert('Please Choose Tuesday Out Time');
        hootueout.focus();
        return false;
        } else if(hootueonval == hoowedoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Tuesday In & Out Time');
            hootueon.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hootueoutval != '') {
        if(hootueonval == '') {
            alert('Please Choose Tuesday In Time');
            hootueon.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(hootueonval == hootueoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Tuesday In & Out Time');
            hootueon.focus();
            return false;
        } 
    }

    if(hootueonval !='' && hootueoutval !='') {
        var g   =   0;
            if (document.postadd.hootueoff.checked==true)
            { 
                //alert('good');
                g++;
            }

        if(g == 1) {
            alert("Don't Choose timing if you choose Closed & Viceversa");
            hootueoff.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoowedonval == '' && hoowedoutval == '' && document.postadd.hoowedoff.checked==false) {
        alert('Please Choose Wednesday Timing or Closed');
        hoowedon.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(hoowedonval != '') {
        if(hoowedoutval == '') {
        alert('Please Choose Wednesday Out Time');
        hoowedout.focus();
        return false;
        } else if(hoowedonval == hoowedoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Wednesday In & Out Time');
            hoowedon.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoowedoutval != '') {
        if(hoowedonval == '') {
            alert('Please Choose Wednesday In Time');
            hoowedon.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(hoowedonval == hoowedoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Wednesday In & Out Time');
            hoowedon.focus();
            return false;
        } 
    }

    if(hoowedonval !='' && hoowedoutval !='') {
            var g   =   0;
            if (document.postadd.hoowedoff.checked==true)
            { 
                //alert('good');
                g++;
            }

        if(g == 1) {
            alert("Don't Choose timing if you choose Closed & Viceversa");
            hoowedoff.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoothuonval == '' && hoothuoutval == '' && document.postadd.hoothuoff.checked==false) {
        alert('Please Choose Thursday Timing or Closed');
        hoothuon.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(hoothuonval != '') {
        if(hoothuoutval == '') {
        alert('Please Choose Thursday Out Time');
        hoothuout.focus();
        return false;
        } else if(hoothuonval == hoothuoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Thursday In & Out Time');
            hoothuon.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoothuoutval != '') {
        if(hoothuonval == '') {
            alert('Please Choose Thursday In Time');
            hoothuon.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(hoothuonval == hoothuoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Thursday In & Out Time');
            hoothuon.focus();
            return false;
        } 
    }

    if(hoothuonval !='' && hoothuoutval !='') {
            var g   =   0;
            if (document.postadd.hoothuoff.checked==true)
            { 
                //alert('good');
                g++;
            }

        if(g == 1) {
            alert("Don't Choose timing if you choose Closed & Viceversa");
            hoothuoff.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoofrionval == '' && hoofrioutval == '' && document.postadd.hoofrioff.checked==false) {
        alert('Please Choose Friday Timing or Closed');
        hoofrion.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(hoofrionval != '') {
        if(hoofrioutval == '') {
        alert('Please Choose Friday Out Time');
        hoofriout.focus();
        return false;
        } else if(hoofrionval == hoofrioutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Friday In & Out Time');
            hoofrion.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoofrioutval != '') {
        if(hoofrionval == '') {
            alert('Please Choose Friday In Time');
            hoofrion.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(hoofrionval == hoofrioutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Friday In & Out Time');
            hoofrion.focus();
            return false;
        } 
    }


    if(hoofrionval !='' && hoofrioutval !='') {
            var g   =   0;
            if (document.postadd.hoofrioff.checked==true)
            { 
                //alert('good');
                g++;
            }

        if(g == 1) {
            alert("Don't Choose timing if you choose Closed & Viceversa");
            hoofrioff.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoosatonval == '' && hoosatoutval == '' && document.postadd.hoosatoff.checked==false) {
        alert('Please Choose Wednesday Timing or Closed');
        hoosaton.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(hoosatonval != '') {
        if(hoosatoutval == '') {
        alert('Please Choose Saturday Out Time');
        hoosatout.focus();
        return false;
        } else if(hoosatonval == hoosatoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Saturday In & Out Time');
            hoosaton.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoosatoutval != '') {
        if(hoosatonval == '') {
            alert('Please Choose Saturday In Time');
            hoosaton.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(hoosatonval == hoosatoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Saturday In & Out Time');
            hoosaton.focus();
            return false;
        } 
    }

    if(hoosatonval !='' && hoosatoutval !='') {
            var g   =   0;
            if (document.postadd.hoosatoff.checked==true)
            { 
                //alert('good');
                g++;
            }

        if(g == 1) {
            alert("Don't Choose timing if you choose Closed & Viceversa");
            hoosatoff.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(hoosunonval == '' && hoosunoutval == '' && document.postadd.hoosunoff.checked==false) {
        alert('Please Choose Sunday Timing or Closed');
        hoosunon.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(hoosunonval != '') {
        if(hoosunoutval == '') {
            alert('Please Choose Sunday Out Time');
            hoosunout.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(hoosunonval == hoosunoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Sunday In & Out Time');
            hoosunon.focus();
            return false;
        } 
    }

    if(hoosunoutval != '') {
        if(hoosunonval == '') {
            alert('Please Choose Sunday In Time');
            hoosunon.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else if(hoosunonval == hoosunoutval) {
            alert('Please Choose different Sunday In & Out Time');
            hoosunon.focus();
            return false;
        } 
    }

    if(hoosunonval !='' && hoosunoutval !='') {
            var g   =   0;
            if (document.postadd.hoosunoff.checked==true)
            { 
                //alert('good');
                g++;
            }

        if(g == 1) {
            alert("Don't Choose timing if you choose Closed & Viceversa");
            hoosunoff.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(document.postadd.hoomonoff.checked==true && document.postadd.hootueoff.checked==true && document.postadd.hoowedoff.checked==true && document.postadd.hoothuoff.checked==true && document.postadd.hoofrioff.checked==true && document.postadd.hoosatoff.checked==true && document.postadd.hoosunoff.checked==true) {
        alert("All Days Can't Be Closed");
        hoomonon.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I have found the solution for myself by using custom methods, which solved my problem